# PHP version automatically changed in IIS SERVER after 5-10minutes

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis, automatic-updates

I have a windows 2008 server with IIS7. The websites are configured with individial application pool.

Few sites are running with PHP 5.4 and few are using PHP 5.6 version. All sites are under Multi-wordpress setup.

One of the plugins that I want to use required PHP atleast 5.6 version and the site in which I want to install this plugin is on PHP 5.4.

The issue:

When I change this site's PHP version from 5.4 to 5.6. It works for few seconds. But, after some time it automatically changes the PHP version back to 5.4.

I have added some web rules with "Helicon Ape". Can this be creating this issue?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Run the report twice to see what are the differences in configuration, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html The diff should reveal enough information to locate the actual cause.